# How to get one value from a Codable struct with multiple values?

Tags: ios, json, swift, codable

I have a large JSON response and inside

```
{
    "availabilityResultList": [
        {
            "availabilityRouteList": [
                {
                    "availabilityByDateList": [
                        {
                            "originDestinationOptionList": [
```

there are 3 separate

```
 "originDestinationOptionList": [
    {
    "fareComponentGroupList":[...]
    },
    {
    "fareComponentGroupList":[...]
    },
    {
    "fareComponentGroupList":[...]
    },
],
```

I can access the values in the first 'fareComponentGroupList' with Codables 
as

```
root.availabilityResultList.first?.availabilityRouteList.first?.availabilityByDateList.first?.originDestinationOptionList.first?.fareComponentGroupList.first?.xxx
```

How do I access values the second and third fareComponentGroupList ?

(I am sorry about these silly questions but I am new with swift Codables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `originDestinationOptionList` returns an array of dictionary, just fetch it from there by index.

```
let originDestinationOptionList = root.availabilityResultList.first?.availabilityRouteList.first?.availabilityByDateList.first?.originDestinationOptionList

let firstobject = originDestinationOptionList[0]["fareComponentGroupList"]
let secondObject = originDestinationOptionList[1]["fareComponentGroupList"]

let firstObjectsFirstItem = firstObject[0]
```

If the above gives error, this works ( Swift 5)

```
let originDestinationOptionList = root.availabilityResultList.first?.availabilityRouteList.first?.availabilityByDateList.first?.originDestinationOptionList

let firstobject = originDestinationOptionList[0].fareComponentGroupList.first

let firstObjectsFirstItem = firstObject?. (add the remaining part)
```

Comment: It gives error 
"Value of type 'OriginDestinationOptionList' has no subscripts" ?
on
let firstobject = originDestinationOptionList[0]["fareComponentGroupList"]


I think it should be let firstobject = originDestinationOptionList[0].fareComponentGroupList

Comment: can you post your codable struct class ?

Comment: @PratapThank you, I figured it out with help from above code, I dunno if its something with swift 5, I had to use the other way, mentioned in my previous comment